# React Testing Library getByLabelText doesn't concat multipart aria-labelledby

Tags: react-testing-library

Along the lines of [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/forms/Multipart_labels), I have a checkbox input labelled by a combination of three different elements: a label, a text field, and then another label.

So the checkbox input has an `aria-labelledby` attribute with a value like `label1 text-field label2`.

```html
<input type="checkbox" aria-labelledby="allow-up-to num words-in-between" />
<div>
  <label id="allow-up-to">allow up to</label>
  <input id="num" type="text" value="0" />
  <label id="words-in-between">words in between</label>
</div>
```

In my test, I'm trying to grab the checkbox based on that label.

I can successfully grab the input with `getByLabelText('text of label1')` or `getByLabelText('text of label2')`, but giving it the full, concatenated label `getByLabelText('text of label1 value of text-field text of label2')` results in nothing being found.

```js
getByLabelText("allow up to"); // works
getByLabelText("words in between") // works
getByLabelText("allow up to 0 words in between") // does not work
```

Trying `getByLabelText('value of text-field')` doesn't work either, but even if I remove the text field from `aria-labelledby`, I still can't get the input using `getByLabelText('text of label1 text of label2')`. [Here's a  codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rtl-aria-labelledby-multipart-vpjpx?from-embed=&file=/src/__tests__/index.js) with a simplified version of the actual UI I'm trying to test.

Is `getByLabelText` supposed to work this way (even though according to the MDN article multiple labels in an `aria-labelledby` should be concatenated by a screen reader)? If so, is there another way I can grab the input by the full label text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this to work with the `getByRole` query instead.

```js
test('gets by complete label', () => {
  const { getByRole } = render(<AllowedWordsBetween />);
  const checkbox = getByRole('checkbox', {
    name: 'allow up to 0 words in between',
  });
  expect(checkbox).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

This might be an issue with the `getByLabelText` query, but I am not sure yet.

---

#### Edit November 2020

The issue [was fixed](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/545#issuecomment-661294872) and included in version `7.21.2`

Comment: Thanks, this will work great for my use case! I might submit a bug about the behavior of `getByLabelText` to try to sort out whether that's intended, but `getByRole` will work just fine for now.

Comment: Perfect! Make sure to link the issue here when you do to keep it documented. I might also give it a go on fixing it if its a real issue. I had some performance issues with `getByRole` so I use it sparingly now, but its definitely useful for more edge cases like this.

Comment: Here's the issue for `getByLabelText`'s behavior: https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/545#issue-612273113 Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: By the way, I'd update `toBeInTheDocument()` to be `toBeVisible` because you almost always don't care if the HTML has it, you care if the user can physically see and interact with it.